# How to install deb dependencies without installing the package?

Tags: dependencies, debian, packaging, dpkg

I have a Debianized project with a `debian/control` file. I know how to use the `mk-build-deps` script from the `devscripts` package to install the build dependencies for this project; i.e., the packages immediately following the `Build-Depends:`.

What I need is a way to do something similar with the *runtime* dependencies; i.e., the packages immediately following the `Depends:` key. Essentially I need a `mk-run-deps` in addition to `mk-build-deps`.

Here's something I hacked together that works okay:

```
export TMP_DEBIAN_CONTROL=$(mktemp)
dpkg-gencontrol \
    -O${TMP_DEBIAN_CONTROL} \
    -P$(mktemp -d) \
    -c"$(pwd)/debian/control" \
    -f$(mktemp) \
    -p'project-name'
sed -ri 's|^Package: |Source: |;s|^Depends: |Build-Depends: |' \
    ${TMP_DEBIAN_CONTROL}
mk-build-deps -irt'apt-get -y' ${TMP_DEBIAN_CONTROL}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Runtime dependencies : Please run `$ dpkg-shlibdeps -t <executable>` with executable and libraries to get a  "Depends=" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there's no proper and general way to fetch the dependencies, except for actually building the binary packages and extracting them from the .debs.

That's because there are going to be dependencies generated at build-time by either helper tooling or even by `debian/rules` via substvars, which might depend on dynamic checks, such as OS vendor, architectures, etc.

If you control the source package and know what are the assumptions then the snippet you provide might work, but it might still miss dependencies injected by say `debhelper` if you are using that.

I guess the real question is why do you need this for? For testing purposes, you would be better served with autopkgtests, which are able to declare dependencies by reference on either the source package build-dependencies or the run-time dependencies for specific binary packages being tested. If this is needed as part of the build process, then those should be listed instead in the source package build-dependencies.

For run-time dependencies you might also be missing `Pre-Depends`, although those are unusual. For build-dependencies, you can use `apt build-dep .`, but that has the problem of not tracking these via a metapackage that can be then removed to drop all the unneeded dependencies.

Comment: > why do you need this for?

At the time I wrote this question, I was tasked with creating "images" encapsulating dependencies for a given package --- one for the build dependencies and another for the run dependencies. I now realize that this task was a poor fit for the normal Debian packaging workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime dependencies : Please run `$ dpkg-shlibdeps -t <executable>` with executable´s and libraries to get a "Depends=" list.

Required setup for "dpkg-shlibdeps -t" :

```
dpkg-shlibdeps-test/     ## random example folder
    ├── debian/
    │   ├── control         ## empty text file
    │   └── substvars       ## text file: created by $ command
    └── gcc-11              ## example executable
```

The dependencies are written to the file *substvars*. This example, gcc, writes: `shlibs:Depends=libc6 (>= 2.31)`

Which you can add to `control` for the package.deb : `Depends: libc6 (>= 2.31)`

---

About debhelper : dh_makeshlibs is a **debhelper** program that automatically scans for shared libraries, and generates a shlibs file for the libraries it finds. `man dh_makeshlibs` https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_makeshlibs.1.en.html Ref. Google , how debhelper can do shlibs

Comment: This answer shows how to expand runtime dependencies via `dpkg-shlibdeps`. I've upvoted it because the commands accomplish (at least a subset) of what I want. One reason I did not mark this as solution: it does not appear to have any debhelper equivalent.